# Briefcase build - Unable to load file

Tags: python, beeware

I am trying to create my first app using briefcase and python through Beeware. I am following the tutorial as listed on the website, however upon running `briefcase build` i recieve the following messages in the console:

```
briefcase build
[helloworld] Building App...
Unable to load file: "src\Hello World.exe"
Setting stub app details...
                                                                                                                    
Unable to update details on stub app for helloworld.
```

the only thing I have noticed that is different from the tutorial is that upon running `briefcase create` I receive this message :

`[helloworld] Created windows\app\Hello World`

Instead of this one as shown in the tutorial

`[helloworld] Created windows\msi\Hello World`

Any help would be greatly appreciated thank you :)

Comment: What version of Briefcase are you using? If it isn't the [current one](https://pypi.org/project/briefcase/), try upgrading.

Comment: I pip installed it so I'm assuming it's the latest version?

Comment: You can check using `pip list` or `briefcase --version`.

Comment: I have version briefcase 0.3.9
I believe this is the latest one?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to say from the details you're provided. The error would be consistent with using the wrong Windows template for the app - but if you're doing the tutorial, you shouldn't be modifying anything that would cause this to be a problem.

The `app` vs `msi` reference isn't anything to be concerned about; that was a change in the most recent version of Briefcase, and we've neglected to update the tutorial to reflect the change.

My initial guess would be that a network error has occurred when Briefcase downloaded the Windows app template. Your Briefcase project should contain a file named `windows\app\Hello World\src\Hello World.exe`. The error you're reporting indicates that file doesn't exist.

My best suggestion for a fix would be to clear out your cookiecutter cache. Look in your home directory (`C:\Users\<your username>`) for a `.cookiecutters` folder; in that folder, there should be a `briefcase-windows-app-template` subfolder. Delete that subfolder; then delete the `windows` folder in your Briefcase project, then re-run `briefcase create`.